# Calling a method to create multiple dynamic form controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this Method that Generates a Panel on the form:

```
private void createPanels(int spacing)
        {
            pnl1.Location = new Point(0, spacing);
            pnl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pnl1.Size = new Size(100, 93);
            tabRotaBuild.Controls.Add( pnl1);

        }
```

I then call this method in form load:

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createPanels(60);            
    }
```

What I want to do next is display this panel again (a new panel) under it with out clearing the existing one. I have a button that generates the new panel when clicked but when I click it the existing panel disappears when the new one is displayed.

This is the code behind the button:

```
int s = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s += 100;
            createPanels(s);

        }
```

Comment: Instead of adding the new panel to a `TabPage`, try adding it to a `FlowLayout` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the method, you are just changing the location of the existing `Panel` and Control.Add method is setting the `Parent` property again, `BorderStyle` and `Size`  have already been set to the same value:

```
private void createPanels(int spacing)
        {
            pnl1.Location = new Point(0, spacing); //notice here
            pnl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pnl1.Size = new Size(100, 93);
            tabRotaBuild.Controls.Add( pnl1);

        }
```

you need to create the new `Panel`
add the `pnl1 = new Panel();` within your method

```
private void createPanels(int spacing)
    {
        pnl1 = new Panel();
        pnl1.Location = new Point(0, spacing);
        pnl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        pnl1.Size = new Size(100, 93);
        tabRotaBuild.Controls.Add( pnl1);

    }
```

or you could declare and instantiate the new panel within the method

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
```

Notice that you won't have the reference on the added panel. You could add each reference to the `List<Panel>` declared outside the method or something similar.